# TypeScript Error - Property or signature expected. I am getting these errors. I can not find out what might be the problem

Tags: typescript

```
import { Countermeasure } from "./classes/Countermeasure";
import { Crash } from "./classes/Crash";
import { Locality, RoadwayType, UnitType } from "./enums";

export interface IAppliedCountermeasure {
  countermeasure: Countermeasure
  unit: UnitType
  unitCost: number
  quantity: number
}

export interface IRoadwayElement {
  readonly id: number
  readonly name: string
  readonly locality: Locality
  readonly peerGroup: number
  readonly roadwayType: RoadwayType
  readonly infoProps: Map<string, string | number>
  readonly riskFactors: Map<string, boolean | number>
  crashes: Crash[]
  appliedCountermeasures: IAppliedCountermeasure[]

  //get infoPropsTable(): [string, string | number][]
  get infoPropsTable(): [string, string | number][]  //line 24
  get riskFactorsTable(): [string, boolean | number][] // line 25

  addAppliedCountermeasure(acm: IAppliedCountermeasure) : void//line 27
  removeAppliedCountermeasure(index: number) : void
  

  //removeAppliedCOuntermeasure2(index:number):void
  //removeAppliedCOuntermeasure1(index:number):void 
  
}
```

[ ERROR ]  TypeScript: ./src/BCLIb/models/interfaces.ts:24:3
Property or signature expected.

```
 L23:  //get infoPropsTable(): [string, string | number][]
 L24:  get infoPropsTable(): [string, string | number][]
 L25:  get riskFactorsTable(): [string, boolean | number][]
```

[ ERROR ]  TypeScript: ./src/BCLIb/models/interfaces.ts:24:7
';' expected.

```
 L23:  //get infoPropsTable(): [string, string | number][]
 L24:  get infoPropsTable(): [string, string | number][]
 L25:  get riskFactorsTable(): [string, boolean | number][]
```

[ ERROR ]  TypeScript: ./src/BCLIb/models/interfaces.ts:24:51
An element access expression should take an argument.

```
 L23:  //get infoPropsTable(): [string, string | number][]
 L24:  get infoPropsTable(): [string, string | number][]
 L25:  get riskFactorsTable(): [string, boolean | number][]
```

[ ERROR ]  TypeScript: ./src/BCLIb/models/interfaces.ts:27:31
',' expected.

```
 L27:    addAppliedCountermeasure(acm: IAppliedCountermeasure) : void
 L28:    removeAppliedCountermeasure(index: number) : void
```

[ ERROR ]  TypeScript: ./src/BCLIb/models/interfaces.ts:34:1
Expression expected.

```
 L34:  }
```

Comment: Are you using an old version of TypeScript?  Accessors in interfaces weren't supported before TS4.3.

Comment: We are using 4.4.2 version here.

Comment: [I can't reproduce this on 4.4+](https://tsplay.dev/mqeXJm) and so your code doesn't seem to be a [mre] of the issue.  Are you *sure* that the version of tsc you are running is indeed 4.4.2?

Comment: It is actually 4.4.2. I am using this file in my other stencil file (.tsc). I upgraded the stencil version. Now its working. Thank you for your input. I got the idea that it might be a version issue.